# Why the database table is not showing Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, eav

I am working on a module for Magento 1.9.X. However, I am not able to create the database table `grided_products`. I have also checked `core_resource`, my module is updating the version also. Below are my codes

> config.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Magento_Grided>
        <version>0.2.0</version>
    </Magento_Grided>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <grided>
            <class>Magento_Grided_Block</class>
        </grided>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <grided>
            <class>Magento_Grided_Helper</class>
        </grided>
    </helpers>
    <models>
        <grided>
            <class>Magento_Grided_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>magento_grided_resource</resourceModel>
        </grided>
        <grided_resource>
            <entities>
                <product>
                    <table>grided_products</table>
                </product>
            </entities>
        </grided_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <grided_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Grided</module>
                <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </grided_setup>
    </resources>
    <catalog>
        <product>
            <type>
                <grided translate="label" module="catalog">
                    <label>Custom Product by Vaibhav</label>
                    <model>grided/product_type_cp</model>
                    <is_qty>1</is_qty>
                    <index_data_retreiver>grided/catalogIndex_data_cp</index_data_retreiver>
                    <price_model>grided/product_price</price_model>
                    <composite>0</composite>
                </grided>
            </type>
        </product>        
    </catalog>
</global>

<frontend>
    <routers>
        <grided>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Magento_Grided</module>
                <frontName>grided</frontName>
            </args>
        </grided>
    </routers>
</frontend>
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <grided>
                <file>gridedtab.xml</file>
            </grided>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_new_action>
            <observers>
                <customproduct_observer_catalog_product_new_action>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>grided/observer</class>
                    <method>hookIntoCatalogProductNewAction</method>
                </customproduct_observer_catalog_product_new_action>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_new_action>
        <catalog_product_edit_action>
            <observers>
                <customproduct_observer_catalog_product_edit_action>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>grided/observer</class>
                    <method>hookIntoCatalogProductEditAction</method>
                </customproduct_observer_catalog_product_edit_action>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_edit_action>          
        <catalog_product_prepare_save>
            <observers>
                <customproduct_observer_catalog_product_prepare_save>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>grided/observer</class>
                    <method>hookIntoCatalogProductPrepareSave</method>
                </customproduct_observer_catalog_product_prepare_save>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_prepare_save>
        <catalog_product_delete_before>
            <observers>
                <customproduct_observer_catalog_product_delete_before>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>grided/observer</class>
                    <method>hookIntoCatalogProductDeleteBefore</method>
                </customproduct_observer_catalog_product_delete_before>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_delete_before>            
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <customproduct_observer_catalog_product_save_after>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>grided/observer</class>
                    <method>hookIntoCatalogProductSaveAfter</method>
                </customproduct_observer_catalog_product_save_after>

                <!-- Obeserver 2nd -->
                <grided_save_product_data>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>grided/observer</class>
                    <method>saveProductTabData</method>
                </grided_save_product_data>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
        <catalog_product_status_update>
            <observers>
                <customproduct_observer_catalog_product_status_update>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>grided/observer</class>
                    <method>hookIntoCatalogProductStatusUpdate</method>
                </customproduct_observer_catalog_product_status_update>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_status_update>            




        <sales_order_item_save_after>
            <observers>
                <customproduct_observer_sales_order_item_save_after>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>grided/observer</class>
                    <method>hookIntoSalesOrderItemSaveAfter</method>
                </customproduct_observer_sales_order_item_save_after>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_item_save_after>
        <sales_order_save_before>
            <observers>
                <customproduct_observer_sales_order_save_before>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>grided/observer</class>
                    <method>hookIntoSalesOrderSaveBefore</method>
                </customproduct_observer_sales_order_save_before>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_before>            
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <customproduct_observer_sales_order_save_after>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>grided/observer</class>
                    <method>hookIntoSalesOrderSaveAfter</method>
                </customproduct_observer_sales_order_save_after>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
        <catalogrule_before_apply>
            <observers>
                <customproduct_observer_catalogrule_before_apply>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>grided/observer</class>
                    <method>hookIntoCatalogruleBeforeApply</method>
                </customproduct_observer_catalogrule_before_apply>
            </observers>
        </catalogrule_before_apply>
        <catalogrule_after_apply>
            <observers>
                <customproduct_observer_catalogrule_after_apply>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>grided/observer</class>
                    <method>hookIntoCatalogruleAfterApply</method>
                </customproduct_observer_catalogrule_after_apply>
            </observers>
        </catalogrule_after_apply>
        <catalog_entity_attribute_save_after>
            <observers>
                <customproduct_observer_catalog_entity_attribute_save_after>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>grided/observer</class>
                    <method>hookIntoCatalogEntityAttributeSaveAfter</method>
                </customproduct_observer_catalog_entity_attribute_save_after>
            </observers>
        </catalog_entity_attribute_save_after>
        <catalog_product_delete_after_done>
            <observers>
                <customproduct_observer_catalog_product_delete_after_done>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>grided/observer</class>
                    <method>hookIntoCatalogProductDeleteAfterDone</method>
                </customproduct_observer_catalog_product_delete_after_done>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_delete_after_done>

        <customer_login>
            <observers>
                <customproduct_observer_customer_login>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>grided/observer</class>
                    <method>hookIntoCustomerLogin</method>
                </customproduct_observer_customer_login>
            </observers>
        </customer_login>
        <customer_logout>
            <observers>
                <customproduct_observer_customer_logout>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>grided/observer</class>
                    <method>hookIntoCustomerLogout</method>
                </customproduct_observer_customer_logout>
            </observers>
        </customer_logout>
        <sales_quote_save_after>
            <observers>
                <customproduct_observer_sales_quote_save_after>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>grided/observer</class>
                    <method>hookIntoSalesQuoteSaveAfter</method>
                </customproduct_observer_sales_quote_save_after>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_save_after>
        <catalog_product_collection_load_after>
            <observers>
                <customproduct_observer_catalog_product_collection_load_after>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>grided/observer</class>
                    <method>hookIntoCatalogProductCollectionLoadAfter</method>
                </customproduct_observer_catalog_product_collection_load_after>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_collection_load_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

> upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.2.php

```
<?php
$this->startSetup();

$table = new Varien_Db_Ddl_Table();

$table->setName($this->getTable('grided/product'));

$table->addColumn(
'entity_id',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
10,
array(
    'auto_increment' => true,
    'unsigned' => true,
    'nullable'=> false,
    'primary' => true
)
);
$table->addColumn(
'created_at',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
null,
array(
    'nullable' => false,
)
);
$table->addColumn(
'updated_at',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
null,
array(
    'nullable' => false,
)
);
$table->addColumn(
'name',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR,
255,
array(
    'nullable' => false,
)
);

$table->setOption('type', 'InnoDB');
$table->setOption('charset', 'utf8');

$this->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$this->endSetup();
```

> Model/Product.php

```
<?php
class Magento_Grided_Model_Product extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('grided/product');
    }
}
```

> Model/Resource/Product.php

```
<?php
class Magento_Grided_Model_Resource_Product extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('grided/product', 'entity_id');
    }
}
```

> Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php

```
<?php
 class Magento_Grided_Model_Resource_Product_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract {
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('grided/product');
    }
}
```

Comment: change version to 0.1.0 in core_resource table.it might be because you have updated version in xml file and then reloaded page so version is updated to 0.1.2 and after that you have added upgrade script in your module.

Comment: @MineshPatel I've deleted the version from core_resource, before that I have tried to rename, now the setup version is not coming in the core_resource table

Comment: check for log  and check your xml is correct

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your version on config.xml to be 0.1.2. 
Another thing I would like to change there is the models in config.xml.
Can you try to change like this:

```
<models>
        <grided>
            <class>Magento_Grided_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>magento_grided_resource</resourceModel>
        </grided>
        <magento_grided_resource>
            <entities>
                <product>
                    <table>grided_products</table>
                </product>
            </entities>
        </magento_grided_resource>
    </models>
```

Let me know if this can help you. Thanks!!

Comment: No, it doesn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by changing below code in the installation script.

```
$installer = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup();

$installer->startSetup();
```

Thanks for the contribution guys :-)